# Problem viewing textfields in java applet

Tags: java, applet, textfield

Extremely new to Java an just playing around with it. I'm trying to add text fields to below a table and for some reason I can't see them. Code is below:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class danTeamProject extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{

danTable aTable;
//private JLabel rowLabel, colLabel;

private JTextField rowNum;
private JTextField colNum;


public void init()  {



    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    this.add(btnStart);
    aTable = new danTable();
    this.add( aTable );

    //rowLabel = new JLabel( "Enter number of rows:" );
    rowNum = new JTextField( 1 );

    //colLabel = new JLabel( "Enter number of columns:" );
    colNum = new JTextField( 1 );

    //this.add (rowLabel);
    this.add (rowNum);

    //this.add (colLabel);
    this.add (colNum);

    rowNum.addActionListener(this);
    colNum.addActionListener(this);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String s = rowNum.getText();
    String sUp = s.toUpperCase();
    rowNum.setText(sUp);
}

}





import javax.swing.*;

class danTable extends JPanel {
public danTable() {
    Object[][] cellData = {
        {"row1-col1", "row1-col2"},
        {"row2-col1", "row2-col2"}};
    String[] columnNames = {"col1", "col2"};
    add(  new JTable(cellData, columnNames) ) ;
   }
}




`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <div>
    <APPLET
      CODE="danTeamProject"
      CODEBASE="."
      width=900 height=900>
      <PARAM name="boxbgcolor" value="cyan">
    </APPLET>
  </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>`
```

Any ideas where the problem is coming from? All the other post I've looked at recommend checking the applet size, but 900x900 should hold everything, right? Thanks in advance...

Also, I know I recently posted a question about this same program. This is simply the best forum to get fast, reliable information...

Comment: It depends what the code in the table class is doing

Comment: It should just be creating a four element table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix Applet and Swing Components:

For instance you cannot place a JTextField on an Applet contentpane.
If you are extending to an Applet not JApplet use TextField instead of JTextField.

```
Button, Label, TextField, Panel  are for Applet
JButton, JLabel, JTextField, JPanel are for JApplet
```

Please take note of the prefix.

Since you are using most of the Swing Components, extend JApplet not Applet

```
public class danTeamProject extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{    ...
     JButton button = new JButton();
}
```

Comment: One more thing though, after you have compile your applet, make sure that you have emptied browser's temporary internet files as well as that of the java(control-panel->java icon).

Answer (score 1):

The default layout for `JApplet` is `BorderLayout`.  Therefore, try adding your components using the permitted `BorderLayout` constraints; e.g.

```
this.add(rowNum, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

If `BorderLayout` is too inflexible for you and you don't want to rely on a third party layout manager I suggest either looking at `GridBagLayout` or else composing your applet from a number of nested `JPanel`s.

Another suggestion: You might want to move your GUI initialisation code from `init()` to the `JApplet` constructor.  This allows you to make your `JTextField`s final; I typically use init() to start any threads the application uses.

Comment: changed code to: this.add (rowNum, BorderLayout.EAST); and this.add (colNum, BorderLayout.WEST);   And still no luck. Thanks for the input, though

Comment: Try adding a call to revalidate() at the end of your init() method.

Answer (score 0):

Which layouter are you using? As I see it, you're using the default layout which allows only a single child (i.e. you can add more but they will be ignored).

Try to add [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to the applet, then the other children should show up.

Comment: I assumed it was a flow layout which would fit the all the components in the window. I'd really like a non-third party solution, but I'll definitely check out MiG. Thanks